# Is it possible to use a constant in the replacement sequence of macro substitution

Tags: c, string, macros, c-preprocessor

In object type macro it is possible below,

```
#define str "this is a string"
```

I want to know is it possible to use this type of string literal in function type macro like following,

```
#define mkstr(a) #a
#define str(s1,s2) mkstr(s1 ## s2 ## "extra")
```

I run this and got error and now i want to know is there any way to use constants in replacement sequence of a function type macro???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Just place the strings together:  the C language accepts that as string constant concatenation.

```
#define str(s1,s2)   s1 s2 "extra"
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a problem in your example in that you have a #defined str twice:

```
#define str "this is a string"
#define mkstr(a) #a
#define str(s1,s2) mkstr(s1 ## s2 ## "extra")
```

Try changing this to:

```
#define str_const "this is a string"
#define str(s1,s2) s1 s2 "extra")
```

Then I think it'll be more clear to you. If you want to you create a string that looks like `this is a string extra` then here is the macro that will do that with the above macros.

```
#define str(s1) str_const "extra"
```